# using javascript to grab multiple id's

Tags: javascript, laravel, getelementbyid

I have a table that lists all of the users invoices, and each invoice contains a pay button to allow them to pay the bill.

I currently have a loop that goes through each invoice and displays each invoice in its own row, and when a user goes to click on the pay button the JavaScript will show a selection box to use a saved card or a new card, if the user chooses a saved card then the JavaScript will show the other select box containing their saved cards, if the new card is chosen then the other input fields will be displayed, right now the showing and hiding part when selecting a saved card or new card ONLY works for the very first row in the table, no other rows work with that JavaScript, I'm sure its because JavaScript is grabbing that first id and stopping there. How can I do this correctly to where it grabs all of the ids and runs the code when the user chooses a saved card or new card on each invoice?

I created a JSFiddle to show my exact situation, can someone modify it to where it will work? I would really appreciate it!
https://jsfiddle.net/s0fbrcw6/1/

**payments.blade.php**

```
@if($payments)
  @foreach($payments as $payment)
      <tr>
          <td><a href="">${{number_format(($payment->price /100), 2, '.', ' ')}}</a></td>
          <td>{{$payment->product_name}}</td>
          <td>{{$payment->created_at->toFormattedDateString()}}</td>
          <td>{{$payment->created_at->addMonth()->toFormattedDateString()}}</td>
          <td>{{$payment->reoccurring}}</td>
          <td>{{$payment->status}}</td>
            @if($payment->status == "Paid")
            @else
              <td>
                  <div class="add-payment-container">
                      <button class="toggle-add-payment mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect pull-right btn-info">
                          @if($payment->reoccurring == "Yes")
                              Subscribe
                          @else
                              Pay Here
                          @endif
                      </button>
                      <div class="add-payment">
                          </br>
                          <form action="{{'/users/payment'}}" method="post"
                                id="checkout-form">
                              <input type="text" name="price" class="hidden"
                                     value="{{$payment->price}}">
                              <input type="text" name="productName" class="hidden"
                                     value="{{$payment->product_name}}">
                              <input type="text" name="paymentID" class="hidden"
                                     value="{{$payment->id}}">
                              <input type="text" name="reoccurring" class="hidden"
                                     value="{{$payment->reoccurring}}">
                              <div class="row">
                                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                                      <div id="paymentMethodDiv"
                                           class="form-group label-floating">
                                          {!! Form::label('paymentMethod', 'Payment Method') !!}
                                          </br>
                                          {!! Form::select('paymentMethod', ['Saved Card'=>'Saved Card','New Card'=>'New Card'], null, ['class' => 'browser-default mdl-selectfield', 'placeholder' => 'Choose Option', 'id' => 'paymentMethod'])!!}
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                                      <div id="savedCardsDiv" class="form-group label-floating" style="display: none;">
                                          {!! Form::label('card', 'Previous Cards') !!}
                                          </br>
                                          {!! Form::select('card', $cardLast4, null, ['class' => 'browser-default mdl-selectfield', 'placeholder' => 'Choose Option', 'id' => 'savedCards'])!!}
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-md-4">
                                      <div id="cardHolderNameDiv" class="form-group label-floating" style="display: none;">
                                          <label class="control-label">Card Holder
                                              Name</label>
                                          <input type="text" id="card-name"
                                                 class="form-control">
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-md-4">
                                      <div id="cardNumberDiv" class="form-group label-floating" style="display: none;">
                                          <label class="control-label">Card Number</label>
                                          <input type="text" id="card-number"
                                                 class="form-control">
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="row">
                                  <div class="col-md-5">
                                      <div id="expirationMonthDiv" class="form-group label-floating" style="display: none;">
                                          <label class="control-label">Expiration
                                              Month</label>
                                          <input type="text" id="card-expiry-month"
                                                 class="form-control">
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-md-5">
                                      <div id="expirationYearDiv" class="form-group label-floating" style="display: none;">
                                          <label class="control-label">Expiration Year</label>
                                          <input type="text" id="card-expiry-year"
                                                 class="form-control">
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-md-2">
                                      <div id="cvcDiv" class="form-group label-floating" style="display: none;">
                                          <label class="control-label">CVC</label>
                                          <input type="text" id="card-cvc"
                                                 class="form-control">
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              {{csrf_field()}}
                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Make
                                  Payment
                              </button>
                              <div class="clearfix"></div>
                          </form>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </td>
          @endif
      </tr>


<script>
    var paymentMethodSelect = document.getElementById('paymentMethod');
    paymentMethodSelect.onchange = function () {
        if (paymentMethodSelect.value == 'Saved Card') {
            document.getElementById("savedCardsDiv").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("cardHolderNameDiv").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("cardNumberDiv").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("expirationMonthDiv").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("expirationYearDiv").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("cvcDiv").style.display = "none";
        } else if (paymentMethodSelect.value == 'New Card') {
            document.getElementById("savedCardsDiv").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("cardHolderNameDiv").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("cardNumberDiv").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("expirationMonthDiv").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("expirationYearDiv").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("cvcDiv").style.display = "block";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("savedCardsDiv").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("cardHolderNameDiv").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("cardNumberDiv").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("expirationMonthDiv").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("expirationYearDiv").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("cvcDiv").style.display = "none";
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Really straight forward. You attempt to use an ID multiple times on the page. ID's are unique. Use a class with `querySelectorAll()` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I did not know that about the ID's and how they are supposed to be unique, really good stuff! So how can I then get the index value for the row that was clicked on in order to show the correct set of divs? Could you either explain or show an example?

Answer (score 0):

**Advice:** use jQuery. For situations like this, it significantly simplifies the js function part of it.

**jsFiddle Solution:** https://jsfiddle.net/brednmuc/4/

**Brief Description:** 
Move away from using HTML IDs for everything and just make attributes that make the most sense for your web application. This methodology allows you to practically define an unlimited number of attributes that you can key certain behaviors off of. This also prevents conflicts with libraries that you may use / integrate with your project.

**Code:** 
**jQuery:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("select[name='paymentMethod']").change(function() {
          var dropdownValue = $(this).val();
          var transactionId = $(this).parent().attr('transactionId');
          switch (dropdownValue) {
            case 'Saved Card':
                $("td[transactionId='" + transactionId + "'] div.savedCardsDiv").show();
              break;
            case 'New Card':
                $("td[transactionId='" + transactionId + "'] div.savedCardsDiv").hide();
              break;
            default:
                $("td[transactionId='" + transactionId + "'] div.savedCardsDiv").hide();
              break;
          };

        });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td transactionId="1">
    <select name="paymentMethod" form="carform" class="paymentMethod">
      <option value="">Select your option</option>
      <option value="Saved Card">Saved Card</option>
      <option value="New Card">New Card</option>
    </select>
    <div class="savedCardsDiv" style="display: none;">
      <select name="savedCards" form="carform" class="savedCards">
        <option value="">Select your option</option>
        <option value="Saved Card">****4242</option>
        <option value="New Card">****5423</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td transactionId="2">
    <select name="paymentMethod" form="carform" class="paymentMethod">
      <option value="">Select your option</option>
      <option value="Saved Card">Saved Card</option>
      <option value="New Card">New Card</option>
    </select>
    <div class="savedCardsDiv" style="display: none;">
      <select name="savedCards" form="carform" class="savedCards">
        <option value="">Select your option</option>
        <option value="Saved Card">****4242</option>
        <option value="New Card">****5423</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```